# Hay forma de simplificar este código?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una duda, esto estaría bien realizado la parte del JS.?
Es que quisiera saber si es posible realizar este código de otra forma, donde al hacer click en el input esto llame a una función y ahí dentro se ejecute todo, pero claro, necesitaría agregar a la etiqueta HTML el evento onclick="mifuncion".
No se si es posible hacer eso o si siempre en JS todo va a ir así donde primero se define una variable por cada evento y de allí hacer toda su ejecución como en addEventListener().

En todo caso de no ser posible, entonces siempre es mejor separar cada archivo JS. según cada evento?

```
let input = document.querySelector('#center-input--search');

input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    let contenedor = document.querySelector('#center');
    let iconoSearch = document.querySelector('.search-left');
    contenedor.classList.toggle('change-search');
    iconoSearch.style.visibility = 'visible';
});

input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    let contenedor = document.querySelector('#center');
    let iconoSearch = document.querySelector('.search-left');
    contenedor.classList.toggle('change-search');
    iconoSearch.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

```
                <div id="center" class="style-content">
                    <i class="bi bi-search search-left"></i>
                    <form class="center--formulario">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar" class="input-search" id="center-input--search">
                    </form>
                    <i class="bi bi-search search-after"></i>
                    <i class="bi bi-mic-fill container-icon"></i>
                </div>
```

Comment: *necesitaría agregar a la etiqueta HTML el evento onclick="mifuncion"*, hacer eso no es aconsejable, es una mala práctica porque viola el principio de *responsabilidad única*, es mejor usar escucha de eventos, como lo tienes ahora. Ver [este enlace](https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_structure_and_behaviour) para más detalles.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con lo planteado por @A.Cedano ni con el dcto que ha incluido. En un página web simple la separación de responsabilidades es posible, una página muestra su contenido aunque no tenga CSS y JS, en este caso el HTML es lo importante. En cambio en una aplicación web, esto ya no es tan cierto. Muchas dependen de JS y sin ello no funcionan en absoluto. Y es aquí donde la separación es una ilusión, donde hayas seteado el evento, ya sea en HTML o en JS es irrelevante, en ambos casos estas dependiendo del otro para que funcione.

Comment: Y para la mayoría de los caso es más limpio y da menos errores colocar los eventos inline que usar addeventlistener

Comment: @Yussef eso no es cierto y te voy a poner un ejemplo práctico. Imaginemos una aplicación más o menos grande donde uses o generes, digamos, cientos o miles de documentos HTML, y hayas puesto la llamada a la función in-line en esos HTML. En un futuro la app evoluciona y hay que pasar un parámetro a la función por ejemplo ... te quiero ver intentando adivinar en que HTMLs llamas a esa función. En cambio, si has usado escucha de eventos y tienes aparte tu archivo `.js`, sólo tendrás que modificar el archivo `.js`, sin tener que modificar los miles o cientos de HTMLs. La diferencia es clara.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una opción, sólo usas la función dentro del listener; para no repetir código. @a-cedano nos podría indicar si esto viola el principio de responsabilidad única o algún otro.

```
let input = document.querySelector('#center-input--search');

input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    Toggle('visible');
});

input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    Toggle('hidden');
});

function Toggle(visibilidad) {
    let contenedor = document.querySelector('#center');
    let iconoSearch = document.querySelector('.search-left');
    contenedor.classList.toggle('change-search');
    iconoSearch.style.visibility = visibilidad;
}
```

Comment: Creo que con el principio se refiere a que "cada cosa a su lugar", o sea, en html lo de html y en js lo de js. Fuera de eso que buena abreviación al código jajaja

Comment: Lo que si, hice la pregunta porqué digamos que debo seguir usando ese archivo.js y debo hacer como 150 o más líneas de código, es un lio si debo tener variables y llamadas a ```addEventListener``` por cada cosa que quiera ejecutar así sueltas